# How can I get my code to iterate through the list?

Tags: python, list

The question is: For every five numbers in the following list from left to right, calculate the means of every five numbers. For example, the first five numbers are 2, 1, 3, 5, and 2, and the mean is 2.6

inputList = [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 3].

This is what I have so far:

```
inputList = [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 3]
for i in inputList:
    total = 0
    avg = 0
    for j in range(5):
        total = total + inputList[j]
        avg = total/5
    print(avg)
```

I'm able to get the mean of the first 5 elements on the list but I can't get the code to keep going after that.

Comment: That list has 21 numbers.  What do you want to do with the extra one?

Comment: `range` has an optional `step` parameter which may help.

Comment: Note that `i` is probably useless to you, as it is a value, not an index.

Comment: @JohnGordon The code should find the average of [2,1,3,4,2] then [1,3,5,2,7] and so on until the last five [9,2,0,1,3].

Comment: Try this - ```means = [sum(L[i: i+5] )/5  for i in range(0, len(L), 5)]```  But it seems that you're looking `rolling window```?

Comment: So you want the average of positions 0-4, then 1-5, then 2-6, and so on?  The question said "calculate the means of every five numbers", which sounds to me like you wanted 0-4, then 5-9, then 10-14, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j in range(5):
        total = total + inputList[j]
```

in this piece of code, you iterate over the same 5 elements over and over again i.e when `i = 0`

- `j = 0`,
- `j = 1`,
- `j = 2`,
- `j = 3`,
- `j = 4`

then again when `i = 1`

- `j = 0`,
- `j = 1`,
- `j = 2`,
- `j = 3`,
- `j = 4`

this continues `i` times.

what you should do is

```
inputList = [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 3]
for i in range(0,len(inputList)):
    if(i<=len(inputList)-5):
        print("starting from index " + str(i))
    total = 0
    avg = 0
    for j in range(i,i+5):
        if(i<=len(inputList)-5):
            print(inputList[j],end=" ")
            total = total + inputList[j]
            avg = total/5
    if(i<=len(inputList)-5):
        print("avg is " + str(avg))
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the means of the *rolling window* of each 5-items?

Try this with more_itertools windowed():

```py
from more_itertools import windowed

L = [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 3]

#list(windowed(L, 5))
#[(2, 1, 3, 5, 2), (1, 3, 5, 2, 7), (3, 5, 2, 7, 3), (5, 2, 7, 3, 7), (2, 7, 3, 7, 4), (7, 3, 7, 4, 6), (3, 7, 4, 6, 9), (7, 4, 6, 9, 1), (4, 6, 9, 1, 0), (6, 9, 1, 0, 2), (9, 1, 0, 2, 4), (1, 0, 2, 4, 8), (0, 2, 4, 8, 9), (2, 4, 8, 9, 2), (4, 8, 9, 2, 0), (8, 9, 2, 0, 1), (9, 2, 0, 1, 3)]

means = [sum(parts)/5 for parts in windowed(L, 5)]
print(means)
# [2.6, 3.6, 4.0, 4.8, 4.6, 5.4, 5.8, 5.4, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 3.0, 4.6, 5.0, 4.6, 4.0, 3.0]
```